# what does it mean (final Customer c=new Customer(); )?

Tags: java, final

I've used final keyword with `class, method, fields`but this the first i'm seeing something like this

```
final Customer c=new Customer();
```

could anyone help me to get what is the use of this?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ what you cannot change/reassign is the value of `c`.

Comment: Declaring a variable as `final` will never allow it to be re-instanced. So in this case, the code `c = SomeOtherCustomerObject;` would throw an error.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Ok. There you go.

Answer (score 1):

it is constant reference - you cannot change its value it can be assigned only once when being defined

[due to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_(Java))

an example:

```
    final String string = "initial value";
    string += " some new content"; //here compiler will raise an error due to you cannot change final value
```

Comment: can't we create clone object using c!! i'd tried but throws  java.lang.CloneNotSupportedException

Comment: it seems to be not about **final** but Customer class. Due to [CloneNotSupportedException reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/CloneNotSupportedException.html) - "Thrown to indicate that the clone method in class Object has been called to clone an object, but that the object's class does not implement the Cloneable interface."